# Convert list of IPNetworks to actual subnets

Tags: python

I have list of IPNetwork objects (from netaddr import IPNetwork) , like below but much longer

```
[IPNetwork('10.1.0.0/24'), IPNetwork('10.1.1.0/24'), IPNetwork('10.1.2.0/24')]
```

I would like to convert it to list of actual subnets :

```
['10.1.0.0/24', '10.1.1.0/24', '10.1.2.0/24']
```

Tried all available IPNetwork methods, can't figure out the elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as simple as a typecast to `str`

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork

li = [IPNetwork('10.1.0.0/24'), IPNetwork('10.1.1.0/24'), IPNetwork('10.1.2.0/24')]
for item in li:
    #Convert to string and print it
    nw = str(item)
    print(type(nw))
    print(nw)
```

The output will be

```
<class 'str'>
10.1.0.0/24
<class 'str'>
10.1.1.0/24
<class 'str'>
10.1.2.0/24
```

As you can `nw` is a string, and I can print it too!